# PHP Paypal SDK get all tranactions

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to setup my code to archive every transaction from the PayPal user's account. I have the PayPal SDK setup and the auth token is stored in my database.

I am using the [paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) and the `PayPal\Api\Search` but I don't know how to use it. Any suggestions?

Whats the best solution to pull all of the transactions from paypal, is it possible?

Comment: This lib have good documentation. Have you checked at http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/ ?

Comment: @hieroshima that shows how to get a payment information, whats the best way to get a list of all the payments

Comment: My bad sorry :). So, acording to that https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#sale_get you must get all sales and pass the sale_id in /v1/payments/sale/ method. For getting sales you must i think get a list of payments.

Comment: @Callum, you need to get list of payments and get transaction for each payment. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The example is here:  [PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/sale/GetSale.php](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/sale/GetSale.php)

You need to get all payments first - https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/ListPayments.php

Comment: Cool thank you. I just realized, it's a sandbox so there's going to be no history of transactions

Comment: When you log into sandbox as a facialiator, you can see all your transactions. And even refunds are available in the sandbox.